How Can I Determine the Amount of Cryptocurrency an Address Deposits into a Protocol?
When attempting to track the amount of cryptocurrency an address has deposited into a DeFi protocol, there are various methods to consider, with cTokens being one approach. However, there may be alternative methods depending on the protocol in question.
For example, in the case of Compound, the amount of ETH an address has deposited can be easily determined by checking how much cETH the address holds. This is because cETH tokens are minted when ETH is deposited into Compound, and the amount of cETH directly reflects the deposit. However, this approach may not work with every protocol, particularly with protocols like Aura or others that do not use cTokens.
In these cases, I would need to manually check the specific token representation for deposits within each protocol, such as governance tokens or liquidity pool tokens, which can be more time-consuming. Protocols may have unique methods of representing deposits, and understanding the specific token associated with each protocol can be a challenge.
Questions:

How can I consistently track the amount of cryptocurrency an address deposits into different protocols?
Is there a more efficient way to determine the corresponding tokens for deposits in protocols like Aura, without manually checking each one?

Any answers are greatly appreciated!
